# "Would have us view" -- is it correct?

Tags: grammar, verbs

It probably is correct since the article is from [Bloomberg.com website](http://noir.bloomberg.com/apps/news?pid=20601039&sid=aEOcF1yyr2XU). However, I am not sure what it really means and why it's correct

> Mark Twain once quipped that “everyone complains about the weather
>   but nobody does anything about it.”
>   Many **analysts would have us view the
>   dramatic increase** in inequality with
>   a similar spirit -- as a natural
>   condition that we should accept
>   without complaint. We should be
>   skeptical of this view -- and not just
>   because it’s obsolete even with regard
>   to the weather.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the phrase "would have us view" is correct. It occurs frequently in the general form, where "view" is substituted by any appropriate verb. I have encountered the term most recently in the form of

> The media would have us believe there
>   was a mysterious launch.

In the context of the quoted article, what the author wants to convey is that many analysts **want to make us see** the dramatic increase in inequality in a similar light to Twain's quip. They **want us to believe** that the rise is comparable to the uncertainty of the weather - everyone complains about both, but no one does anything about either of them.